# unable to upload autopy in python-VSCode in windows 10

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-code, pip, python-3.9, autopy

C:\Users\SB>pip install autopy
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting autopy
Using cached autopy-4.0.0.tar.gz (20 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for autopy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: autopy
Running setup.py install for autopy ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Running setup.py install for autopy did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [20 lines of output]
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\autopy
copying autopy_*init*_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\autopy
running build_ext
running build_rust
error: can't find Rust compiler

```
  If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the need for a Rust compiler.

  To update pip, run:

      pip install --upgrade pip

  and then retry package installation.

  If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> autopy

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.

Comment: The key is "*running build_rust error: **can't find Rust compiler***"

Answer (score 0):

From https://pypi.org/project/autopy/ :

**Requirements**: Rust 1.23.0-nightly 2019-02-06 or later (unless using a binary wheel distribution).

For version 4.0 [binary wheels are available](https://pypi.org/project/autopy/4.0.0/#files) for up to Python 3.8 but not for Python 3.9. Downgrade to Python 3.8 or install Rust.

Comment: okay. i'll give it a try as well.. thanks